# Flickering (vibrating) problems of sprite in cocos2d

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I have sprites which are spawning from bottom to top. They are coming randomly and i haven't used spritesheet for this. The problem is they flicker during their movement from bottom to top. How can i overcome this problem? I am using cocos2d 1.0.1. Thanks for any help.

// Determine where to spawn the target along the X axis

```
    CGSize winSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
    int minX = target.contentSize.width/2;
    //  int maxX = winSize.width - target.contentSize.width/2;
    //  int rangeX = maxX - minX;
    int actualX = (arc4random() % 230) + minX;

    // Create the target slightly off-screen along the right edge,
    // and along a random position along the Y axis as calculated above
    target.position = ccp(actualX,-100);
    [self addChild:target];

    // Determine speed of the target
    float minDuration = 4.0;
    float maxDuration = 12.0;
    float rangeDuration = maxDuration - minDuration;
    //int actualDuration = (arc4random() % rangeDuration) + minDuration;

    // Create the actions
    id actionMove = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:rangeDuration position:ccp(actualX,winSize.height+target.contentSize.height)];

    [target runAction:[CCSequence actions:actionMove, nil]];
```

Comment: you need to show some code for movement of your sprites

Comment: What FPS is your code running at?

Comment: In appdelegate i have [[CCDirector sharedDirector] setAnimationInterval:1.0/60];

Comment: Are you calling `[target runAction:[CCSequence actions:actionMove, nil]];` code once for each target? Another assumption - maybe you set `GL_NEAREST` mode for texture filtering?

Comment: no, it's not for a single but for all the spawning sprites.

Comment: Make sure you don't have more than one move action running per node, otherwise they interfere with each other and cause jumpy or stuttering motion.

Comment: @Steffen: Can you correct my code above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In appdelegate I increased FPS and the sprite movements were smooth. I replaced

[[CCDirector sharedDirector] setAnimationInterval:1.0/60]; with

[[CCDirector sharedDirector] setAnimationInterval:0.5/60];